# Canvas package cause error with Nextjs: Module parse failed: /canvas/build/Release/canvas.node Unexpected character '�'

Tags: webpack, next.js, canvas, fabricjs

I have an `Nextjs13` app.

The app use `canvas` package.

When run dev, i get error: `Module parse failed: /canvas/build/Release/canvas.node Unexpected character '�'`

Then I try to config webpack in `next.config.js`:

```
webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, nextRuntime, webpack }) => {
  config.externals = {
    canvas: "canvas",
  };

  return config;
}
```

But I get another error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createElementNS')` in browser

In terminal, i get errors too:
`Module not found: Can't resolve 'utf-8-validate'`
`Module not found: Can't resolve 'bufferutil'`

In fact, I don't import `canvas` lib in my code, but some lib require it.

How can I fix that?

EDIT:
The `canvas` is used by `fabric.js`